# How to prevent linebreaks in bootstrap tables in mircosoft edge?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, microsoft-edge

I have a simple table with a timestamp.
If you shrink the browser width to <600px, the bottom scrollbar appears so you can move the table left-right, but the columns are **not** broken into multiple lines.

http://jsfiddle.net/9651rn0k/3/

```
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div>id</div>
                </th>
                <th scope="col">
                    <div>fileTimestamp</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>35059970</td>
                <td>2022-07-20T04:39:09</td>
                <td>some</td>
                <td>some</td>
                <td>some</td>
                <td>some</td>
                <td>some</td>
                <td>some</td>
                <td>some</td>
                <td>some</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

BUT: in **microsoft-edge**, the lines are actually broken.
But why? And how can I prevent it, so that the behaviour is the same as in other browsers?

Sidenote: this is just an example, in reality I have a table with many columns that fits 1200px. And there the problem is of course way worse, as ms-edge creates multi-columns always.

Answer (score 2):

Probably adding `.text-nowrap` to the entire table, but maybe there are better approaches?

```
<table class="text-nowrap">
```